# Static friction problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, friction, free-body-diagram

[image: Solution]

I think this is a pretty straightforward problem. “The minimum value of the coefficient of friction to prevent the system from moving” clearly refers to static friction. In this case static friction would happen when the hanging block is suspended in midair and the block on the table is motionless. For this to happen, all the forces in play must be equal. The only forces that can be calculated directly from the given info are the gravitational forces acting on the blocks. The gravitational force of the hanging block must be equal to the tension forces of the other two cords (I say other two cords because even though it looks like one big branched cord it’s easier to think of it as three separate cords: one that’s connected to the $30$ $\rm{kg}$ block, one that’s connected to the wall, and one that’s connected to the $20$ $\rm{kg}$ block). I have two questions.

First, what if there wasn’t a $45°$ angle? The reason I ask is because it says “it should be easy to see that $T_1 \sin45° = T_1 \cos45° = 200\,\rm{N} = T_2$”. I can see how this makes sense because it’s a static friction problem and I can conceptually generalize to say “$T_1 \sinθ= T_1 \cosθ = \rm{the\, gravitational\, force \, on\, the \,hanging\, block} = T_2$”, but mathematically that doesn’t make sense. If $θ$ was any value but $45°$, this wouldn’t be true (right?). Because $\sin30° ≠ \cos30°$ (for example).

Second, what was the purpose of calculating the tension force? I feel like that was pointless cuz the only significance of the tension forces are that they are equal to the gravitational force of the $20$ $\rm{kg}$ block and this helps us solve for the coefficient of friction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Answer to first question:

If $\theta\not=45^\circ$, $T_1sin\theta=200N\not=T_1cos\theta$. Using the knowledge of $\theta$, we need to find out the value of $T_1$ and then $T_1cos\theta$ from there. And since the question involves static friction, $T_2=T_1cos\theta$ and then we can proceed to find out the minimum coefficient of static friction from there as usual.

## Answer to second question:

As the previous answer has said, finding $T_1$ is required to find out $T_2$. In the given question though it does not seem obvious as we can directly write $T_1sin45^\circ=200N=T_1cos45^\circ$ without any need of finding $T_1$ just because $sin45^\circ=cos45^\circ$. However, as I have mentioned in the answer to the first question, if $\theta\not=45^\circ$, $sin\theta\not=cos\theta$ and $T_1sin\theta\not=T_1cos\theta$, so we need to find $T_1$ from $T_1sin\theta$ in order to find $T_1cos\theta$ and then $T_2$ to find the minimum coefficient of static friction.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Good timing too, it helped clarify somethings from the other answer

Answer (score 1):

> If θ was any value but 45°, this wouldn’t be true (right?). Because
> sin30 ≠ cos30 (for example).

If it wasn't 45$^0$ $T_2$ wouldn't be 200 N and the minimum required coefficient of static friction for equilibrium would be different. By inspection you can see that if the angle is less than 45$^0$ the tension $T_2$ would be greater than 200 N. Since the static friction force always matches $T_2$ up to the maximum possible static friction force, the minimum coefficient of static friction needed for equilibrium will be greater if the angle is less than 45$^0$.

> Second, what was the purpose of calculating the tension force?

The tension force $T_1$ determines the tension force $T_2$ and since the static friction force will always match $T_2$ up to the maximum possible static friction force, $T_2$ determines the minimum required coefficient of static friction for equilibrium.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I just want some clarification tho. Wdym when you say “by inspection”? I tried considering θ<45. So it wouldn’t be equal but I guess you would solve for T1 like shown and use this equation: μ(300) = T1cosθ. Is that right? Also for the next part, I want to be sure, is that similar to what I said in the question stem? I think the only difference is I specified equality for this problem and you gave a more general explanation. Please correct me if I’m wrong

Comment: Also, I forgot to mention for the first part, if you do those steps, I’m assuming I’d come to the same conclusion as you, correct?

Comment: By inspection you should be able to see that the smaller the angle, the greater T1 has to be.  Let me ask you this: what do you think the tension T1 would have to be if the angle was 0? The other answer says essentially what I said, but it attempts to provide a complete solution, which, by the way, we are not supposed to do for a homework and exercise type question

Comment: I see what you are saying. If the angle was 0, the tension force would only have a horizontal component and cosθ increases with a decreasing angle (if one considers a 0 to 90 range, every other quadrant can be analyzed directionally with this range; for example cos180 is just cos0 in the opposite direction) And yes I noticed that your answers were very similar and I’m still learning the protocols here. I only picked the other answer for the exact reason you described (it’s a “complete solution”). I wasn’t aware that was frowned upon.

Comment: @Ibby If the angle were 0 the tension $T_1$ would have to be infinite to support the weight, i.e., $$T_{1}\sin\theta=200N$$ $$T_{1}=\frac{200}{\sin\theta}=\frac{200}{0}$$ That would then mean $T_{2}$ would also be infinite and the required coefficient of static friction would also need to be infinite.

Comment: oops. I mixed up T2 and T1 just now. So if I’m understanding this, an angle of 0° in this scenario is not possible, right? I’m not even sure what an infinite coefficient of friction means, but if that’s the minimum required to prevent the system from moving, I’m guessing that means the system can’t be stopped from moving. Or is an infinite coefficient of friction indicate a system that can’t be moved at all? I wanna say thanks for your explanations and patience, physics isn’t my strong suit.

Comment: @Ibby "So if I’m understanding this, an angle of 0° in this scenario is not possible, right? "  You are absolutely right!

Comment: Great. That’s reassuring. Thanks again for your time

Comment: @Ibby Your welcome.